# Object as model in javaScript

Tags: javascript

Sorry if my question is really trivial, just wanted to clarify this.
Imagine I have library class and I have book class.
For example I have some books and they all are stored in this library.
My question is as follows:
Should I use Library class as model to save my books objects there?
Like this:

```
class Library {
    static addBook(book){
        this.books.push(book);
    }

    static getBooksList() {
        return this.books;
    }
}
```

Or will it be  better to create abstract class of Library then create object and use this object as a storage?(model)

Comment: The code presented there allows you to have only one library. Is that intended?

Comment: yes.Probably better solution will be to have it as class and then have objects of library class, because it will give more flexibility. Am I right? And if to think logically, thee can possibly be many libraries (objects).
However in my case library is just a storage of book objects.

Comment: Indeed, I just posted an answer with that advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most flexible way would be to not assume that there will be only one library, even though it may be like that in your current requirements.

So I would not use static methods on your library class, but work with a library *instance*. That way it better represents real life -- a book can one day be in library A and another in library B.

```js
class Library {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.books = []; // Instantiate the books array.
    }
    addBook(book) {
        this.books.push(book);
        // Some extra handling if a book can only be in one library
        if (book.library) book.library.removeBook(book);
        book.library = this; 
    }
    removeBook(book) {
        let i = this.books.indexOf(book);
        if (i === -1) return;
        this.books.splice(i, 1);
        book.library = null;
    }
    getBooksList() {
        return this.books;
    }
}

class Book {
     constructor(title, author) {
         this.title = title;
         this.author = author;
         this.library = null;
     }
}

const book = new Book("1984", "George Orwell");
const library = new Library("The London Library");
library.addBook(book);
console.log("The book " + book.title + " is in " + book.library.name);

const otherLibrary = new Library("The Library of Birmingam");
otherLibrary.addBook(book);
console.log("The book " + book.title + " is in " + book.library.name);
```

If the number of books is going to be large, you should consider using a `Set` instead of an `Array` for `books`. It will provide book removal in *O(1)* time instead of *O(n)*.

Comment: Sorry, how can I instantiate an empty books array?
If I do it just in my library class I got an error;

Comment: Add a line in its constructor. I just added that now.